# How is Firebase storage usage calculated?

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-storage, ionic5

[image]

I have an ionic app that uploads some photos and download the url to store it in mlab, thats fine. I can upload 10 photos at once and download them, thats 100 uploads/downloads. Then I print the photo in a card component.

The thing is that on every click on my home page, I see so many calls to firebase to retrieve image. So I checked my free account SPARK plan on firebase and I reached 20k operations in one day just with 3 users/10 photos(upload/download) and reads in my home page.

As I said I don't get why if the image is loaded from mlab, that should print it once not load them so many times.

```
   private uploadPhotosToFirebase() {
    this.showLoading();
    return Promise.all(this.arrPhotos.map(photo => this.upload(photo)))
      .then((urls: string[]) => {
        console.log(`All success`, urls);
        urls.forEach((url) => this.photosUrlDownload.push(url));
        return Promise.resolve();
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(`Some failed: `, error)
        return Promise.reject();
      });
  }

  private upload(photo: PhotoModel): Promise<any> {
    var storageRef = this.firebaseStorage.storage.ref(this.userId).child(photo.name);

    return storageRef.putString(photo.base64.replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', ''), 'base64')
      .then((snapshot) => {
        // uploaded OK
        return storageRef.getDownloadURL()
          .then((url) => {
            // downloaded OK
            return url;
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            // downloaded KO
            return err;
          });
      }).catch((error) => {
        // uploaded KO
        return error;
      });
  }
```

```
<ion-card>
  <div class="relative">
    <img class="absolute owner-image absolute small-image" src="https://ionicframework.com/docs/demos/api/card/madison.jpg" alt=""> <!-- QUITAR-->
    <ion-card-subtitle class="absolute color-white type-product">{{item.type}}</ion-card-subtitle>
    <img class="main-image" *ngIf="item && item.photos && item.photos[0]" [src]="sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(item.photos[0])">

    <ion-icon (click)="likeProduct()" class="absolute heart color-white small-image" [name]="liking === true ? 'heart' : 'heart-outline'"></ion-icon>
  </div>
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <ion-card-header>
      <ion-card-subtitle>{{item.name}}</ion-card-subtitle>
      <ion-card-title>{{item.price}}€</ion-card-title> <!-- CURRENCY PIPE HERE -->
    </ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-content *ngIf="item && item.description">{{item.description}}</ion-card-content>
  </div>
</ion-card>
```

Comment: It shouldn't do that, when you click the image or as you said when you click on anypage?

Comment: when i click on any page of my app. I upload an image now so you can see, if i click anywhere, it loads it again and in network i see type img and gets converted to txt  and in (memory)

Comment: @MostafaHarb i just uploaded a photo. thanks for your help, im getting crazy

Comment: @MostafaHarb it was because of this: [src]="sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(item.photos[0])", i had this in my card component, but im not sure if its recommended remove the sanitizer, i use it for preview images before upload to firebase, but after upload to firebase is necessary?

Comment: no its not nessessary for sure, even before upload, you can use reader() class to preview the image.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a function call directly in the HTML template is considered to be a bad practice since it will run each time the change detection has fired.

This will cause performance issues and the issue that you have (excessive requests for resources).

The correct way to address this problem is by using a custom pipe and making sure you declare it as a [pure pipe](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#pure-pipes) so Angular will cache the result and will not run it every time the change detection has fired.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";
import { DomSanitizer, SafeUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({
    name: 'safeURL'
})
export class SafeUrlPipe implements PipeTransform {

    constructor(
        protected sanitizer: DomSanitizer
    ) { }

    public transform(value: string): SafeUrl {
        if (!value || value === "none") {
            return "assets/img/no_image_placeholder.png"
        } else {
            return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(value);
        }
    };

};
```